# Does general relativity have an effect of the frequency of light?

Tags: general-relativity, visible-light

if a lightbeam is fired from space to earth is it blueshifted? I heard this happens with special relativity but not sure if it happens with genreal relativity

Comment: Have you looked at [gravitational redshift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift)?

Comment: Ray, you really need to read the Wikipedia article ACuriousMind links then come back to us if you have any specific questions about it. NB the effect is related to the time dilation I discussed in my answer to your last question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is [answered by an easily Googled Wikipedia article](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Not to mention [loads of questions on this site](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=gravitational+red+shift).

Answer (score 1):

It happens in Special Relativity because of time dilation. The time between crests when wave packets are emitted as observed by the emitter, is different to the time between crests when the wave packets arrive and are observed by the receiver. So the observed frequencies are different if there is some time dilation effect between the two observers.

In GR, time dilation effects are also common and they lead to redshifts in a similar manner.